# WebApp/SQL Server - Encrypted connection string vs. trusted connection

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, wcf, security

I need some advice on what would be the best approach to connect to a SQL Server instance from a WCF service hosted in IIS (although I guess the approach applies to any kind of ASP.NET web application).

Two options I am considering:

- Create a Login on SQL Server and using Protected Configuration to secure the connection string in the web.config.
- Running the web application under a specific domain account (created exclusively for this application) and connecting to SQL Server via a trusted connection.

Which of the two would be the recommended approach, or are there other good alternatives that I might consider?

Answer (score 0):

The general best-practice recommendation is to use Windows Authentication instead of SQL authentication whenever it is possible.

Even more, it is highly recommended to set the Server Authentication setting to "Windows Authentication" mode (See CIS Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Database v1.1.0 Security Benchmark, section 3.1 as a reference, you can find it @ https://benchmarks.cisecurity.org/tools2/sqlserver/CIS_Microsoft_SQL_Server_2012_Database_Engine_Benchmark_v1.0.0.pdf).

I hope this information helps.